# the module is not recognized in python (flask)

Tags: python, flask, module, runtime-error

learning flask and new to web dev here ,
made the directories as below .
[in folder named website and in a subfoder named templates make a file *init*_.py and outside the website folder ,main.py is there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rda7.png)

code in **init**.py

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY']='madkrish'

    return app
```

code in main.py

```
from website import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__== '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When i run the main function the following errors comes:

No Module named 'website'

[given above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ax29T.png)

Can someone please correct me where i am wrong i need to go further in the tutorial to the next step.

Comment: just use `import create_app`.

Comment: @nobleknight if i use import create_app then the error comes as No module named 'create_app'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your folder structure, you need to import from templates, so:

```py
from templates import create_app
```

It should works.

VSCode will still marks it as error, you need to configure it to inlcude your templates folder in the Python Path